# FragmentActivity com ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, actionbar

Gostaria de criar um *Drawer* com um *ActionBarDrawerToggle*.
Estou seguindo este [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)!
Minha única alteração é que estou estendendo um `FragmentActivity` e não uma `Activity` como o exemplo.
Quando vou executar ocorre um `NullPointer` na seguinte linha:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Pois o `getActionBar()` está nula!.
Alguém saberia como colocar um  `ActionBarDrawerToggle` em uma `FragmentActivity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julgo que está a usar a *v7 appcompat library*.
Para ter acesso ao *ActionBar* a sua *Activity* deverá herdar de *ActionBarActivity* ou melhor de [AppCompactActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) já que *ActionBarActivity* foi considerada obsoleta.

Poderá então obter uma referência ao *ActionBar* usando:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

[AppCompactActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) é uma [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) com suporte ao *ActionBar*.

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou corretamente! Muito obrigado!